# How to select strings not containing a word using regular expression?

Tags: r, regex

I try to remove data that doesn't contain the word `data`.

I can do the following

```
rm(list = ls()[!grepl(pattern = "data", ls())])
```

But I know there is a pattern parameter in ls which I can make the code look nicer, I have already tried

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^[^data]"))
```

But it doesn't work, so how to remove data that doesn't contain the word using regular expression.

**Update**:

please note this pattern may not take **Perl** style.

Comment: `ls` won't take `perl` style `pattern`  The one you are tyring to match is checking the characters not to match and not the word as a whole

Comment: I would like to match so that I can remove all the variables not containing "data", elegantly.

Comment: thanks akrun, but I would like to know if anyone could come out with a pattern inside ls.

Comment: Sure, have a great day

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `[` with `^` it is specifically checking for the characters and not the word as a whole.  As `ls` wouldn't take the `perl` style regex, it may be better to make use of `invert` and `value` option in `grep`

```
rm(list =grep(pattern = "data", ls(), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use negative lookahead:

```
(?!.*data)
```

Meaning "assert that what follows is not: zero or more of any characters followed by `data`".

I'd suggest also turning on single line mode by `(?s)` - dot will match also newline character `(?s)(?!.*data)`

If pattern is matched, you can delete the string, as it doesn't contain `data`.

Comment: Error in grep(pattern, all.names, value = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '(?!.*data)', reason 'Invalid regexp'

Comment: please note this pattern may not take Perl style